# Multi-Line link with image

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, razor

I have not developed web pages/apps in over 15 years and a lot has changed.  I am working in Visual Studio 2019, ASP.NET, and razor pages...

I'd like to create a set of links that are have a border and wrap if the screen is not wide enough.  I thought this would be something simple, but I cannot figure it out.  I've spent all week on this and perhaps I am not searching for the correct terms or I don't really know what I am looking for.

I can get close with a table, something like (1 row, multiple cells):

```
<td style="
                width:128px;
                height:80px;
                border:2px solid black;
                font-size:xx-small;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-size:64px;
                background-image:url(/Icons/@item.Icon);
            ">
    <table>
        <tr><td style="text-align:right; width:120px"><b>A1: @item.Test1</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td style="text-align:right;"><b>A2: @item.Test2</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td style="text-align:right;"><b>@item.Note1</b> &nbsp;<img src="/Icons/@item.State1a" height="8" width="8" />&nbsp;<img src="/Icons/@item.State2a" height="8" width="8" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td style="text-align:right;"><b>@item.Note2</b> &nbsp;<img src="/Icons/@item.State1b" height="8" width="8" />&nbsp;<img src="/Icons/@item.State2b" height="8" width="8" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <a href="/Details?item=@item.Id">
        @item.Description
    </a>
</td>
```

There are 2 issues with the current approach...

1. It does not wrap when the screen width is too small
2. Only the item description is clickable

I put the image in the background because some of the values in the text (item.Test1, item.Test2), push the text to the left overlaying the image.

Any suggestions?

Perhaps point me to come code to dynamically generate an image of what I am looking for (I'd prefer a CSS solution, but creating an image would be acceptable).

Comment: wrap all the table in one big `<a>` tag. If it's break the appearance, give to the `<a>` style `display:block`

Comment: Why are you using tables with fixed dimensions in something you're apparently trying to make responsive?

Comment: @IrishChieftan:  Tables are not a requirement, I only used them because of my limited knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I finally came up with was to drop the table, wrap the links (buttons) in a paragraph, replace the td tag with button give it an onclick='location', and keep the same style and sub-table layout.

Now the buttons wrap for different screen sizes and have the same look and feel as the old ones that were wrapped in a table.